# Python - Filter a dataset based on column values of another dataset

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dictionary

I have two datasets:

First dataset looks like this:

```
| Key 1 | Value 1 | Key 2 | Value 2 | Key 3 | Value 3|

| abc   |  True   | bcd   | False   | cde   | False  |
| bcd   |  False  | cde   | True    | def   | False  |
| def   |  False  | abc   | True    | None  | N/A    |
```

Second data looks like this:

```
| abc    | bcd     | cde   | def     | status    |

| False  |  False  | True  | False   |  Success  |
| True   |  False  | False | False   |  Failure  |
| False  |  True   | True  | True    |  Success  |
| False  |  False  | True  | False   |  Failure  |
| True   |  False  | False | False   |  Success  |
| False  |  True   | True  | True    |  Success  |
| False  |  False  | True  | True    |  Success  |
| True   |  False  | False | False   |  Failure  |
| True   |  True   | True  | False   |  Failure  |
```

Now for every row in first data set, i want to pickup the key value pairs and apply them as filters in second data set i.e subset the rows from second subset. Then count the number of rows applicable, No. of success, No of failures.

So the first data set transforms to :

```
| Key 1| Value 1| Key 2| Value 2| Key 3| Value 3| Row Count | Successes| Failures|

| abc  |  True  | bcd  | False  | cde  | False  | 3         |1         |2   |
| bcd  |  False | cde  | True   | def  | False  | 2         |1         |1   |
| def  |  False | abc  | True   | None | N/A    | 4         |1         |3   |
```

**Explanation:**

In First row (of first datset): abc - True; bcd - False; cde - False. Applying these filters in the second dataset, we will be left out with the following rows:

```
| abc    | bcd     | cde   | def     | status    |

| True   |  False  | False | False   |  Failure  |
| True   |  False  | False | False   |  Success  |
| True   |  False  | False | False   |  Failure  |
```

Numbers of rows : 3
Failure : 2
Success :1

Comment: What did you try? Show your code.

Comment: Can you change some sample data to both dataframes and add expected output - all rows? Because is necessary [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Is possible change `abc` column to `False, True, False` and `cde` to `True, False, True`, also `Value 3` to `False, True, NaN` for more general solution?

Comment: @jezrael added the values. Thanks for the comment

Comment: Can you check my answer? I get a bit different output. Also is possible explain more `Row Count` column?

Comment: If I not understand it, is psosible add more rows to both dataframes? e.g 3-4 new ones?

Comment: @jezrael Added more examples. Let me know if it is not clear. Request you to modify the answer accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
from collections import Counter

#create dictionaries of boolean values for each row
L = [{a:b for a, b in (zip(v[::2], v[1::2])) if isinstance(b, bool)} 
          for k, v in df1.T.to_dict('l').items()]
print (L)
[{'abc': True, 'bcd': False, 'cde': False}, 
 {'bcd': False, 'cde': True, 'def': False}, 
 {'def': False, 'abc': True}]

#match with df2 and count index values by Counter
df22 = df2.set_index('status')
out = [Counter(df22.index[np.logical_and.reduce([df22[k] == v 
       for k, v in x.items()])]) for x in L]
print (out)
[Counter({'Failure': 2, 'Success': 1}), 
 Counter({'Success': 1, 'Failure': 1}),
 Counter({'Failure': 3, 'Success': 1})]

#create DataFrame
df2 = pd.DataFrame(out, index=df1.index).fillna(0).astype(int)
#insert total row for first position
df2.insert(0, 'Row Count', df2.sum(axis=1))
#join together
df = df1.join(df2)
print (df)
  Key 1  Value 1 Key 2  Value 2 Key 3 Value 3  Row Count  Failure  Success
0   abc     True   bcd    False   cde   False          3        2        1
1   bcd    False   cde     True   def   False          2        1        1
2   def    False   abc     True  None     NaN          4        3        1
```

Comment: i didnt undertsand the question till i saw the answer, :)

Comment: @anky_91 - ya, a bit busy, but after dinner check it.

Comment: @jezrael Your answer is only taking care of "True" filters, It also need to take care of "False" filters as we are finding the exact match of occurence of df1 in df2